# POST request from angular 2 frontend to springboot service fails in chrome browser

Tags: angular, google-chrome, spring-boot, http-status-code-403

I have an angular frontend which sends a JSON POST request to the SpringBoot backend. The request URL /auth/** is authorized in SpringBoot with permitAll. I also only get the following error response in chrome browser: 403 (forbidden) invalid CORS request. In other browsers (firefox, IE) it works.

The security configuration of SpringBoot is as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
                .csrf().disable()

                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()

                // don't create session
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) //;

                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*.*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()    
                .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()    
                .antMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()   
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()  
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()   
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()  
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login");

        // Custom JWT based security filter
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // disable page caching
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }
```

Comment: If I add the @CrossOrigin annotation with the request URL annotation it works. It is strange because the angular frontend and the springboot service are packaged together and have the same base URL

Comment: In Chrome not only the origin of the domain name, also the protocol (http / https) has to correspond.